# Execution continues with await

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

Im new to async await and Im not sure it works as I think it does. Search results have been inconclusive and I need someone to point me in the right direction.

I have two functions, addOrder() which calls the getDistance() function that does some api work and then sets the 'mileage' in my data function(vue application). However, it seems that the await isnt working as if I try to console.log the 'mileage' right after awaiting the getDistance function, it still shows it as empty (what it was initialized as). Any insight appreciated.

Add to order function:

```
async addToOrder(){
   await this.getDistance()
   console.log(this.mileage) //problem is here, it shows the initialized value instead of the value changed in getDistance
}
```

Get distance func

```
 async getDistance() {
      var origin = `${this.pickupPair.lat},${this.pickupPair.lng}`
      var dest = `${this.dropoffPair.lat},${this.dropoffPair.lng}`
      let miles
      //using google maps loader
      loader.load().then(() => {
        const service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService()
        service.getDistanceMatrix(
          {
            origins: [origin],
            destinations: [dest],
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
            unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL,
            avoidHighways: false,
            avoidTolls: false,
          },
          (response, status) => {
            if (status !== 'OK') {
              alert('Error was: ' + status)
            } else {
              const originList = response.originAddresses
              const destinationList = response.destinationAddresses

              this.mileage = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text
              this.mileage = this.mileage.replace(' mi', '')
              this.getCost()
            }
          }
        )
      })
    }
```

Comment: await this.getDistance().then(res=>console.log(res)) ?
it also looks like you aren't returning anything with getDistance? the pattern I know is you grab data, and return it - then you manipulate objects once you have a response, if you manipulate stuff inside the callbacks - the 'this' keyword can get weird.

Answer (score 0):

When you called loader.load().then() you basicly asked it to do it async.
So javascript in that getDistance will continue on and let that call happen later.
Meaning getDistance will return before anything inside .then happens.

There are a couple of solutions to this, but first:

Do you know if **getDistanceMatrix** can be called as a Promise?

Like this:
**service.getDistanceMatrix(...).then()**

Or can you only get the result by passing in the callback function?

Here are some possible solutions, depending on if the getDistanceMatrix is a Promise or not.

```
// Full promise chaining
function getDistance() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    var origin = `${this.pickupPair.lat},${this.pickupPair.lng}`;
    var dest = `${this.dropoffPair.lat},${this.dropoffPair.lng}`;
    let miles;

    loader.load().then(() => {
      const service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();

      service.getDistanceMatrix(
        {
          origins: [origin],
          destinations: [dest],
          travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
          unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL,
          avoidHighways: false,
          avoidTolls: false,
        },
        (response, status) => {
          if (status !== "OK") {
            alert("Error was: " + status);
          } else {
            const originList = response.originAddresses;
            const destinationList = response.destinationAddresses;

            this.mileage = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text;
            this.mileage = this.mileage.replace(" mi", "");
            this.getCost();
            resolve();// We are done, and calling function await will stop.
          }
        }
      );
    })

  })
}

// Full async/await
async function getDistance() {
  var origin = `${this.pickupPair.lat},${this.pickupPair.lng}`
  var dest = `${this.dropoffPair.lat},${this.dropoffPair.lng}`
  let miles

  await loader.load();

  const service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService()

  // If getDistanceMatrix is a promise and possible to await
  const response = await service.getDistanceMatrix(
    {
      origins: [origin],
      destinations: [dest],
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
      unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL,
      avoidHighways: false,
      avoidTolls: false,
    },
  )

  if (response.status !== 'OK') {
    alert('Error was: ' + status)
  }

  console.log(response.data)
}
```

Comment: It looks like it can be called as a promise if Im not mistaken.

Comment: Try using await in front of the call instead of .then.

Comment: it actually couldnt be called as a promise, but the first method of promise chaining worked great! Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Great! Yeah sometimes thirdparty libriaries support both styles. Promises and callbacks. So unfortunatly when they just handle the callback way of getting the result you have to do something similar to my first solution. Where I'm basicly forcing everything to be a promise :)